# localStorage.getItem() : Could not fetch any data in form the local storage by the key

Tags: reactjs

I could not fetch any data in form the local storage by the key but data is there with the associate key in react js. Please help me.
All time it giving me null return value

Comment: Please reveal the mystery code by editing your question to include it so we may best assist you here.

Comment: Are you setting a value for local storage first? E.g. ```localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')```? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: no not getting error while storing data. but can't get the data by localStorage.getitem('key name') . giving me null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i fixed the issue. the problem is i set the value with the key named 'token:' and while calling the value from local storage i was always calling it with 'token'. So that's why i did not get the value first

Answer (score 2):

Store the item from the place you want like this

```
localStorage.setItem("sample", "1234567");
```

and receive the item like this where you want

```
localStorage.getItem("sample")
```

Comment: is there any issue using this ' ' instead of " ".

Comment: No you can use single or double quotes

Comment: Now here is the issue . the getItem() is not giving me back the value with the key here .